# How to rename multiple files in bash by changing year name

Tags: bash

I have multiple files named as DOWN_1982_1.31.nc, DOWN_1982_2.31.nc .... DOWN_1982_12.31.nc. I want to rename them to DOWN_2040_1.31.nc, DOWN_2040_2.31.nc .... DOWN_2040_12.31.nc. How to do so using preferably an one liner bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no spaces or funky characters in the file names, and all files are in one folder:

```
for f in DOWN* ; do echo mv "$f" "${f/1982/2040}" ; done
```

If the mv commands look ok to you, do it again without the echo.